# How to use getElementById on an element in a javascript template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spotify

I have a placeholder that looks like this:

```
<div class="select-playlist">
    </div>
```

I append the following html into the placeholder:

```
<script class="select-playlist-template" id="select-playlist-template">
  <h1>SELECT A PLAYLIST</h1>
  <select class="all-playlists" id="all-playlists" style="width: 50%">
  </select>
  <button class="btn btn-default" id="load-playlist">Load the Playlist</button>
  <button id="playlist-recommendation" class="playlist-recommendation">FIND MY MOST COMMON RELATED ARTISTS</button>
</script>
```

Now I want to start a function when the user clicks the buttons in the html above with the code:

```
document.getElementById('playlist-recommendation').addEventListener('click', function getArtistsAndRelated() {...}, false);
```

But I get the error 'getElementById(...) is null. Clearly the code doesn't recognise the id even when it has been loaded into the file. How can I add a click function to the buttons in a javascript template. The only solution I can see is putting the buttons in the placeholder and using $('select-playlist').show when I want to load the div, but the other approach seems cleaner.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I assume the append is happening AFTER the getElementById is called? That could be why, but can only speculate without seeing the code

Comment: "*I append the following html into the placeholder*". Please provide the code that does that. Also note your `script` element has no type attribute, and that means `text/javascript`. Either use a custom `type`, or use [HTML5 templates](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use event delegation to smooth over issues with dynamic content. Since you mentioned having jQuery available, using its built-in support for event delegation with `.on()` makes that easy:

```
$(document).on('click', '.playlist.recommentation', function() {
  // getArtistsAndRelated here.
});
```